# could not create the driver from nhibernate.driver.sqlclientdriver, nhibernate, version=5.3.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=aa95f207798dfdb4

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I faced the below error fluentNhibernate in .net 6 project but the same code is working in framework 4.8.

Error: could not create the driver from nhibernate.driver.sqlclientdriver, nhibernate, version=5.3.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=aa95f207798dfdb4

My code in .net 6 is:

```
public class DatabaseContext
{
    private static ISessionFactory session;

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSession()
    {
        const string connectionString = "Data source=SQLEXPRESS;Database=**;Integrated Security=True";

        if (session != null)
        {
            return session;
        }
        var sqlConfiguration = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(connectionString);

        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(sqlConfiguration)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TokenMapping>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    public static NHibernate.ISession SessionOpen()
    {
        return CreateSession().OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add nuget package [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) to your project to make `NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver` work under .NET Core.

Also consider using `NHibernate.Driver.MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver` instead (available since NHibernate v5.3) which depends on [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) nuget package. Microsoft will favor development of new features in this new NuGet package from now on (see [details](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/)). In Fluent NHibernate:

```
var sqlConfiguration = MsSqlConfiguration.
  .MsSql2012
  .Driver<MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver>() //needs Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nuget package
...
```

Comment: Thank you alot bro, the night I found out the problem which was, not the installing the package.